# Error on Tensorflow JS predict() on React Native App - High memory usage in GPU: 1179.94 MB, most likely due to a memory leak

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I'm developing a React Native (managed by Expo) simple app which should let to detect/recognize text from live stream coming from a TensorCamera.

I found these [tflite models](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-text-detection,image-text-recognition&subtype=module,placeholder) and, thankfully to the [amazing job of PINTO0309](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-convert-tflite-to-model-json-weights/17174/15), I've converted to json + bin files.

Following [official documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.8.0/#cameraWithTensors) I've coded like that the `TensorCamera onReady` callback:

```
const handleCameraStream = (images: IterableIterator<tf.Tensor3D>, updateCameraPreview: () => void, gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
        const loop = async () => {
            if(!images) return;

            if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames === 0) {
                const imageTensor = images.next().value;
                if(!imageTensor) return;
                
                if (model) {
                    const tensor4d = imageTensor.expandDims(0);

                    const predictions = await model.predict(tensor4d.cast('float32'))
                    console.log(' - Predictions: ', predictions);

                    tensor4d.dispose();
                }

                imageTensor.dispose();
            }

            frameCount++;
            frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames;
            
            requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        };

        loop();
    }
```

**TensorCamera:**

```
let textureDims;
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') 
    textureDims = { height: 1920, width: 1080 };
else 
    textureDims = { height: 1200, width: 1600 };

<TensorCamera
    style={ styles.camera }
    cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
    cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
    useCustomShadersToResize={false}
    type={CameraType.back}
    resizeHeight={800}
    resizeWidth={600}
    resizeDepth={3}
    onReady={handleCameraStream}
    autorender={true}
/>
```

Unfortunately I get a memory leak warning and then app crashes!

```
WARN  High memory usage in GPU: 1179.94 MB, most likely due to a memory leak
```

I've tried both `tf.tidy()`, `tf.dispose()` functions but the errors persists.

What I'm doing wrong?
How can I improve memory handling?

Thank you